# Entity Framework context automatically creating new entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an EF Code First database and before I create an entity in the database, I'm checking if a related entity exists first, associate it, then create the entity.

For example, assume I have an Order entity which has a related User entity. If the Order entity wants to be stored in the database, I first check if the User already exists. If it does, I want to change the Order so that it's User property is equal to the existing User entity rather than creating a new record.

```
// check for an existing user and associate them instead of creating a new one
var existingUser = await _userRepository.GetAsync(u => u.Username == order.User.Username);
if (existingUser != null)
{
    order.User = existingUser;
    Context.Entry(order.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

The following line in the code above is causing the problem:

```
order.User = existingUser;
```

Before that line, the "Context.Users" has an existing two records (correct). But after that line, it contains three records (incorrect) where two of them are exactly the same.

Why does the code not simply assign the **existingUser** object to the **order.User** property instead of creating a new record in the Context?

Comment: Can you put up the definition of your User class, along with the Order's User property? And in what class is the code you posted in? (I.e. an OrderRepository?) Does your UserRepository and this code share the same DbContext reference? I suspect that this may be a case of 2 dbContexts combined with a mapping where the PK is not set up correctly so order.User is being considered a new entity. If the PK was set up at a minimum you might have gotten a duplicate PK attempting to insert a record that already exists.

Comment: What's the state of `order` at that point? I think you should show some more surrounding code. Also, why don't you just attach `order.User` instead of replacing it?

Comment: @GertArnold you are an absolute genius!  I have been stuck on this for some time and your comment around attaching instead of replacing works beautifully.
Used this as a reference to your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14476027/1448448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to GertArnold I was able to solve it by doing the following:

Replace:

```
order.User = existingUser;
Context.Entry(order.User).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

With:

```
Context.Entry(order.User).CurrentValues.SetValues(existingUser);
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14476027/1448448

> It was most probably because oldEntry and newEntry had
>   different value of entity key. It is possible that it fails because
>   you cannot change a key of existing entity.